# Move multiple agents using seize block (ResourcePool) to Destination

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to move multiple agents from multiple locations using ResourcePool (Seize Block) and delivery to destination.

The concept is, the truck has a capacity of 4 units i.e. it can transport 4 agents (Good/Product) at a time. But with the traditional method seize block transports one agents at a time.

Is this possible or should I be using Pickup and Dropoff function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your `Seize` block to force the truck to seize all units at once:
[image]

If you apply that, the truck will exit the `Seize` block only once your 4 resources are seized.

Comment: Hello,

Maybe I didnt explain very well. So I am trying to explain again,

Truck is the resourcespool (only 1 truck available). 

And the orders are the agents in source block. So when orders are generated, the resources are send to the agent location to pick it up and deliver to the home location of resourcepool. 

My goal is that, trucks (resourcepool) will go to every agents arrived in multiple source block without releasing/going back to home location to delivery only one agent. 

I want the truck to pick up 4 available order/agent and then go back to home location and release.

Comment: tbh, this is easier modelled with state charts, not with process flow charts. See tutorial here: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/index.html